Flexible employee shifting based on workload
I want to efficiently distribute the existing workforce by using flexible shifting. I clearly defined the constraints on my code but still having negative and nonbinary numbers output. Can anyone help to solve the problem?
I tried several options. Sometimes I get all zero values sometimes error but not the values I want. Here is My code:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pulp import LpProblem, LpMinimize, LpVariable, lpSum, LpStatus, value



# Define parameters
days = df.columns[1:]
workload = df.iloc[:, 1:]
workload=workload.values.ravel(order='F')
hours = df["Hour"].values
num_employees = 24
max_hours_per_week = 40
shift_length = 8
rest_hours = 16

# Create problem
prob = LpProblem("Workforce_Scheduling", LpMinimize)

# Define variables
employee_work = LpVariable.dicts("employee_work", (days, hours, range(num_employees)), cat="Binary")

# Define auxiliary variables for absolute differences
abs_diff = LpVariable.dicts("abs_diff", (days, hours), lowBound=0, cat="Continuous")

# Objective function: Minimize the total workload difference
prob += lpSum(abs_diff[d][h] for d in days for h in hours)

# Constraints for absolute differences
for d in days:
  for h in hours:
    total_employees = lpSum(employee_work[d][h][e] for e in range(num_employees))
    prob += total_employees == df[d].iloc[h]  # Ensure exact number of employees

# Each employee works at most 40 hours per week
for e in range(num_employees):
    prob += lpSum(employee_work[d][h][e] for d in days for h in hours) == max_hours_per_week

# Each employee works in 8-hour shifts followed by 16 hours rest
for e in range(num_employees):
    for d in days:
        for h in hours:
            if h + shift_length <= 24:
                prob += lpSum(employee_work[d][h2][e] for h2 in range(h, h + shift_length)) == shift_length * employee_work[d][h][e]
            else:
                next_day = days[(days.get_loc(d) + 1) % len(days)]
                prob += (lpSum(employee_work[d][h2][e] for h2 in range(h, 24)) +
                         lpSum(employee_work[next_day][h2][e] for h2 in range(0, (h + shift_length) % 24))) == shift_length * employee_work[d][h][e]
            for rest in range(1, rest_hours + 1):
                prob += employee_work[d][(h + rest) % 24][e] + employee_work[d][h][e] <= 1

# Solve the problem
prob.solve()

# Debugging outputs
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])
print("Objective value:", value(prob.objective))

# Generate the schedule
schedule = pd.DataFrame(index=range(24 * len(days)), columns=["Day", "Hour","workload"] + [chr(97 + i) for i in range(num_employees)])
schedule["Day"] = np.repeat(days, 24)
schedule["Hour"] = np.tile(hours, len(days))
schedule["workload"] = workload

for d in days:
  for h in hours:
    for e in range(num_employees):
      schedule.loc[(schedule["Day"] == d) & (schedule["Hour"] == h), chr(97 + e)] = value(employee_work[d][h][e])




# Display the schedule
print(schedule)

